# Correct implementation of weighted K-Nearest Neighbors

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, knn

From what I understood, the classical KNN algorithm works like this (for discrete data):

- Let **x** be the point you want to classify
- Let **dist(a,b)** be the Euclidean distance between points **a** and **b**
- Iterate through the training set points **pᵢ**, taking the distances **dist(pᵢ,x)**
- Classify **x** as the most frequent class between the **K** points closest (according to **dist**) to **x**.

---

How would I introduce weights on this classic KNN? I read that more importance should be given to nearer points, and I read [this](http://www.data-machine.com/nmtutorial/distanceweightedknnalgorithm.htm), but couldn't understand how this would apply to discrete data.

For me, first of all, using **argmax** doesn't make any sense, and if the weight acts increasing the distance, than it would make the distance worse.  Sorry if I'm talking nonsense.

Comment: That page already applies to discrete points.  You simply divide the influence of each of the `K` nearest neighbours by its distance from `x`.  Just where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at where/how I would apply this "influence change" on the classical algorithm I mentioned

Comment: *For me, first of all, using argmax doesn't make any sense, and if the weight acts increasing the distance, than it would make the distance worse, sorry if I'm talking nonsense.*  => No but the weight you assign is inversely proportional to the distance. So *argmax* would make sense

Comment: I believe that "the influence" a point has over another is the **distance**. So I wonder, if this is really the influence, why/how would I modify it multiplying by some factor

Comment: The distance is not the raw influence, rather the distance is inversely proportional to the influence. so influence = distance^(-1)

Comment: That link also lacks lot of information, for example, what would **v**, **f(xᵢ)** and **δ(v, f(xᵢ))** be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple example with three classifications (red green blue) and the six nearest neighbors denoted by R, G, B.  I'll make this linear to simplify visualization and arithmetic

```
R B G x G R R
```

The points listed with distance are

```
class dist
  R     3
  B     2
  G     1
  G     1
  R     2
  R     3
```

Thus, if we're using unweighted nearest neighbours, the simple "voting" algorithm is 3-2-1 in favor of `Red`.  However, with the *weighted* influences, we have ...

```
red_total   = 1/3^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2  = 1/4 + 2/9 ~=  .47
blue_total  = 1/2^2 ..............................=  .25
green_total = 1/1^2 + 1/1^2 ......................= 2.00
```

... and `x` winds up as `Green` due to proximity.

That lower-delta function is merely the classification function; in this simple example, it returns `red | green | blue`.  In a more complex example, ... well, I'll leave that to later tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

***Okay, off the bat let me say I am not the fan of the link you provided, it has image equations and follows a different notation in the images and the text.***

---

So leaving that off let's look at the regular *k-NN* algorithm. regular k-NN is actually just a special case of weighted k-NN. You assign a weight of 1 to *k* neighbors and 0 to the rest.

1. Let *W<sub>qj</sub>* denote the weight associated with a point *j* relative to a  point *q*
2. Let *y<sub>j</sub>* be the class label associated with the data point j. For simplicity let us assume we are classifying birds as either crows, hens or turkeys => discrete classes. So for all j, *y<sub>j</sub>* `<-` {crow, turkey, hen}
3. A good weight metric is the inverse of the distance , whatever distance be it Euclidean, Mahalanobis etc.
4. Given all this, the class label *y<sub>q</sub>* you would associate with the point *q* you are trying to predict would be the the sum of the *w<sub>qj</sub> . y<sub>j</sub>* terms diviided by the sum of all weights. You do not have to the division if you normalize the weights first.
5. You would end up with an equation as follows *somevalue<sub>1</sub>* . crow + *somevalue<sub>2</sub>* . hen + *somevalue<sub>3</sub>* . turkey
6. One of these classes will have a higher *somevalue*. The class witht he highest value is what you will predict for point *q*
7. For the purpose of training you can factor in the error anyway you want. Since the classes are discrete there are a limited number of simple ways you can adjust the weight to improve accuracy